# How to remove .php extention from url using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to remove php extension my url and question marks replace with slashes

```
http://eeroju.in/telugu/post.php?post_id=348
```

to

```
http://eeroju.in/telugu/post/post_id/348
```

I am using below code

```
        RewriteEngine On

        # Unless directory, remove trailing slash
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/telugu/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
        RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/telugu/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
        RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
        ---
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^route-page\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /route-page.php [L]
        </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

include this in your .htaccess code
 **

```
 Options +Indexes +MultiViews
```

** 
in your html code, to link to another page do this

```
<a href="next-page">Click here</a> to go to next page
```

next-page is an .php file, but can be rendered to on the browser without the .php extension.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - the main problem is how to get PHP files to be run by PHP without the `.php` extension. It requires an Apache configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following settings

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```